# Angular tests in github action error on an unknown file: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: angular, testing, github-actions

I am trying to configure github actions for an angular project, i've successfully done it for eslint. Now i'm doing it for the tests.

Here is my workflow:

```yaml
name: Tests
on:
  push:

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - name: Cache node modules
        id: cache-nodemodules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        env:
          cache-name: cache-node-modules
        with:
          # caching node_modules
          path: node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-
            ${{ runner.os }}-build-
            ${{ runner.os }}-
      - name: Install Dependencies
        if: steps.cache-nodemodules.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: |
          npm install
      - name: Build
        run: |
          npm run build -- --configuration production
      - name: Test
        run: |
          npm run test:prod",
```

And in my `package.json` i have theses scripts

```json
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:prod": "ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadless --watch=false --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
```

When i go to github i have an error on the stage named "Test"

```
Run npm run test:prod",
/home/runner/work/_temp/faafcf18-b7cb-4071-89de-92596eeeab41.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

I don't understand the error, when i run the command locally everything works fine. And since this file is not part of my project i don't know where to look.

Comment: I'm not Angular expert, but that last like doesn't look right to me. Are you sure you need `",` at the end of it?

Comment: Omg, i feel stupid that i missed it, it was that line i removed `",`and it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
The comment from *Gregory Boutte* was the solution.

I'm posting his solution as the Answer  to make it more discoverable for others.

When a GithubAction executes it will generate a bash-file in `/home/runner/work/_temp/` with the contents of the `run` command.

The command was `npm run test:prod",` - the last two characters were a mistake (probably a copy-paste from a script in package.json) and this caused the EOF-error complaining about `"`

Change it to `npm run test:prod`

Due to a copy-paste mistake when adding a command from a package.json file to a githubaction yml file

**Orginal**

```
  - name: Test
        run: |
          npm run test:prod",
```

**Fixed:**

```
  - name: Test
        run: |
          npm run test:prod
```

alternatively as a one-liner

```
  - name: Test
        run: npm run test:prod
```